# Updating a model into another one in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, save

I have a model called `Details` that contains a method that updates some attributes with calculations by using another model's (`Summary`) attributes. I call that method into a `before_save`to make `Details`' attributes update automatically when I modify an entry. I would like to make my `Details`' attributs update when I modify my entries in the `Summary` model. What I'm searching is something that could be used like that :

```
def update
    @summary = Summary.find(params[:id])
    if @summary.update_attributes(params[:summary])
      (Details.update_all_attributes)
      flash[:notice] = "Updated!"
      redirect_to edit_summary_path(@summary)
    else    
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

See the line : `Details.update_all_attributes`. All my `Details`' attributs would be saved and recalculated because of the `before_save` I have put. How can I do that ? Thanks.

---

Edit :

I just found the answer. I did a loop that saves all my entries.

```
def update
    @summary = Summary.find(params[:id])
    if @summary.update_attributes(params[:summary])
       @details = Details.all
       @details.each do |detail|
        detail.save!
       end
       flash[:notice] = "Updated!"
       redirect_to edit_summary_path(@summary)
    else    
       render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Hope I will help some of you !

Comment: Are those two models related in some way, or is it a class method you're trying to call?

Comment: I just found what I was searching. I will post my answer in 8 hours because I can't do it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fat models, skinny controllers:

Model

```
class Summary < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :recalculate_details

private

  def recalculate_details
   Detail.all.each {|d| d.save! }
  end
end
```

Controller

```
def update
    @summary = Summary.find(params[:id])
    if @summary.update_attributes(params[:summary])
       flash[:notice] = "Updated!"
       redirect_to edit_summary_path(@summary)
    else    
       render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```